# Sum table by week and day of week using slicer power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table as following called sales_base and I want sum the sales by day of WEEK and put it into a bar chart. For example, if a choice the date '04/01/2023' the first bar will be 2220, the second 545, the third 45545, the fourth 6565 and the last three remains bars will be zero (graph below)

| date | sales |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 2020 |
| 01/01/2023 | 200 |
| 02/01/2023 | 545 |
| 03/01/2023 | 45545 |
| 04/01/2023 | 6565 |
| 05/01/2023 | 3453 |
| 06/01/2023 | 35545 |
| 07/01/2023 | 4353 |
| 08/01/2023 | 4354 |
| 09/01/2023 | 43534 |
| 10/01/2023 | 34544 |
| 11/01/2023 | 23423 |
| 12/01/2023 | 34234 |
| 13/01/2023 | 332423 |
| 14/01/2023 | 23233 |
| 15/01/2023 | 32333 |
| 16/01/2023 | 32323 |
| 17/01/2023 | 23234 |
| 18/01/2023 | 43443 |
| 19/01/2023 | 32323 |
| 20/01/2023 | 3434 |
| 21/01/2023 | 43444 |
| 22/01/2023 | 344343 |
| 23/01/2023 | 34343 |
| 24/01/2023 | 12212 |
| 25/01/2023 | 3453 |
| 26/01/2023 | 434443 |
| 27/01/2023 | 23323 |
| 28/01/2023 | 4344343 |
| 29/01/2023 | 4355 |
| 30/01/2023 | 544554 |

I though in the following code to adress this issue but it doesn't worked well.

Firstly I create two columns to my dataset

```
week_num = WEEKNUM(sales_base[date])
week_day = WEEKDAY(sales_base[date])
```

After that, I created the following measure:

```
WEEK = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(sales_base[sales]),YEAR(sales_base[date]) = YEAR(MAX(sales_base[sale])),sales_base[week_num] = WEEKNUM(MAX(sales_base[date])),sales_base[week_day]<=WEEKDAY(MAX(sales_base[sales])))
```

I ploted the measure above on the Y_axis and the column week_day on x-axis but it displayed all bars when for instance I selected in the slicer 'o4/01/2023' which isn't useful for me.

I want a result similarly to the graph below when I select 04/01/2023 for instance:

[image]

The slicer:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify this bit" "I ploted the measure above on the Y_axis and the column week_day on x-axis but it displayed all bars when for instance I selected in the slicer 'o4/01/2023' which isn't useful for me." Did you mean it **did not** show all the bars?

Comment: When I select '04/01/2023' I want the sum by day of week until 04/01/2023 and I want the graph display for me 0 for the days 05/01/2023,06/01/2023 and 07/01/2023. Sor for example, if I select the day 08/01/2023 (sunday and therefore first day of week) the graph will display for me only the sum of values for this day and 0 for the days 2,3,4,5,6 and 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a separate table for the chart. Create a new Calculated table with:

```
Dim WeekDay = DATATABLE(
    "weekday num", INTEGER, "weekday str", STRING,
    {
      { 1, "Sun" },
      { 2, "Mon" },
      { 3, "Tue" },
      { 4, "Wed" },
      { 5, "Thu" },
      { 6, "Fri" },
      { 7, "Sat" }
    }
  )
```

Once the table is created, click on the `weekday str` and in Column Tools, select `Sort by column` and select `weekday num`

Create two new measures:

```
Avg Sales = AVERAGE(sales_base[sales])

Avg by Weekday = COALESCE([Avg Sales]('sales_base'[week_day] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim WeekDay'[weekday num])), 0)
```

Now update your chart to use:

```
X-Axis: 'Dim WeekDay'[weekday num] OR 'Dim WeekDay'[weekday str]
Y-Axis: [Avg by Weekday]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I select the period 01/01/2023 to 08/01/2023 I want the graph be similarly to your second graph with value only for sunday. If I select the period untill 09/01/2023 I want the graph display values only for sunday and monday, etc. The graph must be take in consideration only the maximum date of the slicer

Comment: `Avg by Weekday = COALESCE([Avg Sales]('sales_base'[week_day] = SELECTEDVALUE('Dim WeekDay'[weekday num]) && 'sales_base'[week_num] = MAX('sales_base'[week_num])), 0)`  When happy please accept answer for the benfit of all.